Trying to install apache2 on Ubuntu
The package linux-modules-6.8.0-45-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-generic

Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing. What Ubuntu are you using? What command did you run that gave that error?
